# How to run HiveSQL with DynamoDB local

Tags: hive, amazon-dynamodb

As the title, I have installed DynamoDB local and HiveSQL on my Ubuntu successfully. But when run a Hive query in command line to create a table as

```html
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Hive_ProductCatalog
(Id string,Title string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"dynamodb.table.name" = "ProductCatalog",
"dynamodb.column.mapping" = "Id:Id,Title:Title");
```

then I got the error

> Failed with exception org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error in loading storage handler.org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

I took a look on Google but did not find the library for DynamoDBStorageHandler class to put into the lib folder of Hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DynamoDBStorageHandler is made available to customers running Hive queries on the AMI that are provisioned for EMR jobs. Instead, you may consider setting [dynamodb.endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/EMR_Interactive_Hive.html) to the host you have DynamoDB Local running on. That way you may be able to use DynamoDB Local as the backend for Hive queries.